# My raspberry pi 4 b has problems with ethernet

Tags: ethernet, ethernet-port

First off I dont have a monitor or ap isolation.

Secondly I dont have my computer working it died, i only have my android phone.

I borrowed my friends computer to flash with raspberrypi's windows flasher (.exe) I didn't plug it in to my Samsung as I am a little anxious about it making folders and files

The orange green color is still

I have attached a picture on how it looks, so that you can understand better.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/P06qp.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EExxq.jpg
Using HG-255S router ( I have access to the root user )
Sorry my device camera is glitchy

Comment response :

*-*

Mr. brown, I cant setup ssh as I cant find it on the network such as router interface, nmap, advanced ip scanner, or raspberrypi.local

*-*

Mr. Brown, I see thanks for telling me! In any chance of this working on my mobile android it makes folders like android and a file
Does that break the os?

*-*

Mr. Brown, I’ve configured my router, what is the next step?

Comment: Have you set up SSH or some other mechanism of connection to your Pi in the absence of a monitor?  If so, have you tried it?  If not, how do you plan to use the Pi?  Please edit these answers into your question rather than adding them as comments.  Two other things:  Both the orange light (speed) and green light (traffic) are normal, although the green light should flicker except in the presence of heavy traffic.  Also, many people are reluctant to click links.  It's better to describe what you see when talking about lights, or include a diagram to describe a circuit.

Comment: You will have to set up SSH before you can use it.  You do that on your friend's computer.  See Step 3 at this link: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/headless.md  As far as finding the machine on the network, is there a DHCP server available on your network?

Comment: Whether you can set up SSH using an Android phone is another question, and one you should ask separately.  (I don't know the answer, but perhaps someone will.)  Meanwhile, back to the Ethernet problem... do you have a DHCP server on your network?

Comment: Yes, my router. It used to work, I dont know why but it broke

Comment: If there's no DHCP, the Pi has a link-local address, on a different network entirely from everything else, and so it's inaccessible.  Since you have access to the router, your first step should be to fix DHCP; without it, *no* new device will work.  Then you can ask a new question about configuring Raspbian using your phone.

Comment: Ok, got it! My DHCP is enabled so now what do I do?

Answer (score 1):

With DHCP enabled, if all is otherwise well, your Pi should get an address on your local network.  You will be able to see it in your router's tables or as `raspberrypi.local` assuming your phone is mDNS-capable.

You now need to configure your microSD card to start SSH on boot.  The "start SSH" part is covered in the link I posted in the comments.  You want to do the configuring with your phone, which is beyond the scope of this question.  So, please *ask a new question* about using an Android phone to configure Raspbian's boot partition.